# Float values changes. Not sure why

Tags: c++, floating-point, cuda, 32bit-64bit

I have two files.

- TreeSearch.cpp
- TreeSearchCUDA.cu

In TreeSearch.cpp I have:

```
int* searchTree(vector<TreeNode> &tree, vector<ImageFeature> featureList)
{
    float** features = makeMatrix(featureList, CHILDREN);
    float* featuresArray = makeArray(features, featureList.size());
    float* centroidNodes = convertTree(tree);

    int numFeatures = featureList.size();
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        cout << "C++ " << centroidNodes[j] << endl;
    }
    cout << "" << endl;

    int* votes = startSearch(centroidNodes, tree.size(), featuresArray, numFeatures);

    return votes;
}
```

startSearch exists in TreeSearchCUDA.cu which looks like this:

```
int* startSearch(float* centroids, int nodesCount, float* features, int featuresCount)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        printf("CUDA %f \n", centroids[j]);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now if we look at the output it looks like this:

```
C++ 0
C++ 2.52435e-29
C++ 0
C++ 2.52435e-29
C++ 6.72623e-44
C++ 1.26117e-44
C++ 2.03982e+12
C++ 4.58477e-41
C++ 0
C++ 1.26117e-44

CUDA 0.000000 
CUDA 0.000000 
CUDA 0.000000 
CUDA 0.000000 
CUDA 0.000000 
CUDA 0.000000 
CUDA 2039820058624.000000 
CUDA 0.000000 
CUDA 0.000000 
CUDA 0.000000
```

The results are not the same. Does anyone have any ideas? :)
I have an idea that it is because some parts of the code is compiled with -m64 and some parts are not. However it is not possible to change this. When linking the objects I use -m64.

I hope someone has a solution or explanation :)

Comment: Could you explain which part of code is compiled with 64bit and which part with 32bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like from your output that CUDA is approximating really small floats to `0`. All your inputs are really small floats or `0` except `2.03982e+12`. `2.03982e+12` remains the same in the output. Are your centroids supposed to be really small?

Comment: I am so stupid. I had not noticed that. The results are the same. If I use scientific notation the results are correct.

Answer (score 1):

`float`s are not exact, you can use the header `<limits>` to get information about how many digits in your (decimal) float you can safely use and that are guaranteed to remain unchanged.

```
 #include <limits>

 ...

 std::cerr << std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10 << std::endl;
```

On my system this outputs `6`, which means I can be sure that the float will be exact when using up to 6 decimals. But a number consisting of more decimals are not considered to be exact, `numeric_limits<float>` doesn't guarantee that these numbers will stick and remain 100% unchanged.

Another thing I might add is that `printf` doesn't print floating points as `std::ostream` does, there are often internal difference on how floating points are handled and printed. I don't think `printf` with `%f` as default "trusts" as many decimals as `std::ostream` in scientific representation.

---

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  float x = 0.1234599999; // 10 digits

  std::cout.precision (10);
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

output (on my system)

```
0.1234600022
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/NVIDIA-CUDA-Floating-Point.pdf, in "Devices with compute capability 1.2" [or 1.3 for floats], "Denormal numbers (small numbers close to zero) are flushed to zero." Denormal numbers are the ones between ~1.4e−45 and ~1.18e−38 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), so that explains how your e-41 and e-44 numbers wound up at 0. I'm not sure about the e-29 ones, but something similar could have happened.